# Can I send file and string data in one list to server using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm a student studying Android programming. I am currently working on a project to make an app. I am currently in the process of communicating with the server using Retrofit2. I have to send a list of one file and one string data set to the server. When the server team receives and uses this list, it must be able to call and use as follows:

```
data[0].text
data[0].file
```

To do this, I have defined Retrofit service in many ways, including the following code, but failed to send it correctly:

```
// retrofit service definition

interface Service {
    @Headers("Authorization: ${BuildConfig.TOKEN}")
    @Multipart
    @POST("/post")
    fun addPost(
        @Part data: List<MultipartBody.Part>
    ): Call<PostResponse>
}
```

```
// creating a list

            val list: List<MultipartBody.Part> = viewModel.listData.value!!.map {
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("text", it.text)
                val image = File(it.image)
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "file",
                    image.name,
                    image.asRequestBody()
                )
            }
```

```
// inside api call function

            val service = AppClient.retrofit?.create(Service::class.java)
            service?.addPost(
                data = list
            )?.enqueue(object : Callback<PostResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<PostResponse>,
                    response: Response<PostResponse>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<PostResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("PostResponse", "API CALL FAILED $t")
                }

            })
```

Can I send a list where one file and one string data are one set? How do I modify this to ensure that the server team uses this list correctly?

It's my first time writing a question, so it may be lacking a lot. Please let me know if there is any information missing. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

To send a list where each item contains both a file and a string data to the server using Retrofit2, you need to create a custom data model class that represents each item in the list. Let's call this data model `DataItem`. This `DataItem` class should contain fields for both the string and file data.

Here's how you can define the `DataItem` class:

```kotlin
data class DataItem(
    val text: String,
    val file: MultipartBody.Part
)
```

Now, you can create a list of `DataItem` objects and send it to the server. Here's an example of how to do that:

```kotlin
// Create a list of DataItem objects
val dataItemList = viewModel.listData.value!!.map {
    val textPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("text", it.text)
    val imageFile = File(it.image)
    val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
        "file",
        imageFile.name,
        imageFile.asRequestBody()
    )
    DataItem(textPart, filePart)
}

// Call the API with the list of DataItem objects
val service = AppClient.retrofit?.create(TravelService::class.java)
service?.addTraveller(dataItemList)?.enqueue(object : Callback<PostResponse> {
    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<PostResponse>,
        response: Response<PostResponse>
    ) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            // Handle the successful response
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<PostResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.e("PostResponse", "API CALL FAILED $t")
    }
})
```

In this code, you create a list of `DataItem` objects, where each object contains both a string part (`textPart`) and a file part (`filePart`). Then, you send the list of `DataItem` objects to the server.

Make sure to modify your Retrofit service to accept a list of `DataItem`:

```kotlin
interface Service {
    @Headers("Authorization: ${BuildConfig.TOKEN}")
    @Multipart
    @POST("/post")
    fun addTraveller(
        @Part data: List<DataItem>
    ): Call<PostResponse>
}
```

Comment: This answer looks like a copy-paste from ChatGPT

Comment: Type mismatch occured in here 'DataItem(textPart, filePart)' because required one is String but found one is MultipartBody.Part.  Should I change String type to MultipartBody.Part type in data class?

Comment: @blonded yes change it to string.

Comment: Sorry. It didn't help.